# Why am I getting undefined for props in the Child component?

Tags: reactjs, undefined

I am new to React and have been struggling at this problem for a few days now. Basically I have an App component, Parent component, and Child component. My problem is I am trying to pass props from the Parent to Child but I am getting undefined for every prop that I attempt to pass according the the console log. Any ideas why I am unable to retrieve the proper value for any of the props? Thanks in advance!

Below is a sample of my Parent component:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

function Parent() {

    const sets = [
        {
            name: "Set1",
            categories: [
                {
                    name: "Cat1",
                    att1_opt: ["A", "B", "C"],
                    att2_opt: [null],
                    att3_opt: ["1", "2", "3"]
                },

                {
                    name: "Cat2",
                    att1_opt: ["A", "D"],
                    att2_opt: ["AA", "BB", "CC"],
                    att3_opt: ["4", "5"]

                },
                {
                    name: "Cat3",
                    att1_opt: [null],
                    att2_opt: [null],
                    att3_opt: ["6"]
                },
            ],
        }
    ];


    const [set, setSet] = useState('--Set--');
    const [category, setCategory] = useState('--Category--');
    const [att1, setAtt1] = useState('--att1--');
    const [categories, setcategories] = useState([]);
    const [att1_opt, setAtt1_opt] = useState([]);


    const changeSet = (event) => {
        setSet(event.target.value);
        if (event.target.value !== '--Set--') {
            setcategories(sets.find(cat => cat.name === event.target.value).categories);
        }

    };

    const changeCategory = (event) => {
        setCategory(event.target.value);
        if (event.target.value !== '--Category--') {
            setAtt1_opt(categories.find(category => category.name === event.target.value).att1_opt);
        }

    };

    const changeatt1 = (event) => {
        setAtt1(event.target.value);

    };


    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <form>
                        <div>
                            <label for="set">Set:</label>
                            <select value={set} onChange={changeSet}>
                                <option>--Set--</option>
                                {sets.map(cat => (
                                    <option value={cat.name}>{cat.name}</option>
                                ))}
                            </select>
                            <br />
                        </div>

                        <div><label for="category">Category:</label>
                            <select value={category} onChange={changeCategory}>
                                <option>--Category--</option>
                                {categories.map((category) => (
                                    <option value={category.name}>{category.name}</option>
                                ))}
                            </select>
                            <br />
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label for="att1_requirement">att1:</label>
                            <select value={att1} onChange={changeatt1}>
                                <option>--att1--</option>
                                {att1_opt.map(att1 => (
                                    <option value={att1}>{att1}</option>
                                ))}
                            </select>
                            <br />
                        </div>

                        <Child />

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div >
        </>
    );
}

export default Parent;
```

And here is the Child component:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function Child(props) {


    console.log("props " + props.category)
    return <p>Please Work</p>
};

export default Child;
```

Comment: _`<Child />`_  you haven't passed any props

Comment: I was under the impression that you can pass all of the variables from the Parent to the Child by passing props as an argument in the function. Is that not the case? Could you please advise the proper way to pass all of the props?

Comment: https://react.dev/learn/passing-props-to-a-component

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly pass each prop you want the child the have. I'm assuming you want the parent's `category` state to be the child's `category` prop:

```js
<Child
    category={ category }
/>
```

In this situation, the intention of the programmer may seem "obvious" since the prop and the variable share the same name, but this is not always the case. React can't assume this for you.

Here's what more complex specifying of child props could look like. As you can see, the possibilites are vast:

```js
<Child
    onChangeCallback={ isLoggedIn ? myCallback : myModal }
    displayText={ "Foo" }
/>
```

---

As a tip, in the child, you can destructure the props which may make it clearer what range of props the child expects:

```js
function Child({
    category,
    anotherProp,
    isExampleProp = true //etc
}) {
```